# Set query size when performing scroll request via Spring Data Elasticsearch Repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot application and am using spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.2 to create a `scroll` request to fetch large sets of "book"s from elasticsearch. The setup looks something like this:

```java
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {

   Stream<Book> findByAuthorName(String authorName);

}

// and client code invokes like
try (Stream<Book> books = bookRepository.findByAuthor(authorName)) {
   return books.toList();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // handle
}
```

This does work, but by default the scroll request size is 500 (i.e. the generated query has `size: 500`). I'd like to be able to change this value to fetch larger result sets, but am unsure how to do so.
I've tried updating the repository method to accept a `Pageable` and then invoking with a larger page size. E.g.

```java
public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
   // Add Pageable parameter
   Stream<Book> findByAuthorName(String authorName, Pageable page);

}

// Pass pageable with larger size
try (Stream<Book> books = bookRepository.findByAuthor(authorName, Pageable.ofSize(1_000))) {
   return books.toList();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // handle
}
```

However, the generated query doesn't seem to be impacted.

```json
{
  "_source": { ... },
  "from": 0,
  "query": { ... },
  "size": 500, <----- HOW TO CHANGE?
  "track_scores": false,
  "version": true
}
```

How can I change the query size?

Edit:
Adding relevant docs about scrolling with repositories:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.1.2/reference/html/#elasticsearch.scroll
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.1.2/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

Comment: Why do you want to change this size? Do you want to have less calls to Elasticsearch in the background? Or do you want to limit the size of elements returned?

Comment: I'd like to have fewer calls to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current release (5.1) the `Pageable` is not taken into account for repository methods returning a `Stream<E>`, there always the default size of 500 is used.

I created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2720) for this, it's implemented and merged and will be contained from 5.2-RC1 on.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to use `PageRequest` as guided in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/).

```
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(1, 20));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I am specifically trying to adjust the scroll generated via repositories. If I can't figure it out, then I may have to do what you suggest and use an entirely different query type like Pages, but I'd prefer to get repositories working satisfactorily if possible.